# How does an entity get printed into a page after going though the page callback function?

Tags: routes

This following code snippet is the value of `page callback` from `hook_menu()`. However, I cannot connect `entity_view` and the page template. How can I print or access the `entity_view` returned in this code from  my page template?

```
function example_task_view($task) {
  drupal_set_title(entity_label('example_task', $task));
  return entity_view('example_task', array(entity_id('example_task', $task) => $task), 'full');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the array of fully-loaded entity objects to the [entity_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7) function, not only the id.

For example:

```
...
$entity = entity_load('example_task', array($task);
return entity_view('example_task', $entity, 'full');
```

Comment: How do I access that fully-loaded entity in the page template?

Comment: If you look at the example code in my answer, you load the entity in the page callback function and return the view of it, which is a render array. The entity should already be printed on the page without any template. However, if you need to use your own template, i.e. override the `page.tpl.php`; you should be able to print it manually in the template like `print render($page['content']);` but I didn't test it.